# SubSonic 3 - Simple repository - One to many relations

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3, one-to-many

It's the first time I use Subsonic.

Let say I have those classes :

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

An employee is related to a store with is hired date. This means that in the database I will have a middle table With StoreId, EmployeeId, StartDate, EndDate

## UPDATE

An employee can work to the StoreA from 2009-01-01 to 2009-04-04 and work for StoreB from 2009-04-05 to ... And I don't want that my data table repeat all the information of my employee each time an employee change the store he working for. In this example employee have only a name, but lets say an employee got 10 property (adress, age, gender ...)

How could I achieve that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment and the updated question it looks like you want something like the following:

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class StoreEmployee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
    public DateTime HiredDate { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Maybe I express wrongly myself. I mean an employee can work to the StoreA from 2009-01-01 to 2009-04-04 and work for StoreB from 2009-04-05 to ... And I don't want that my data table repeat all the information of my employee each time an employee change the store he working for. In this example employee have only a name, but lets say an employee got 10 property (adress, age, gender ...)

Answer (score 0):

You'll actually need a many-to-many relationship which will join an Employee record to a Store Record, with a payload of Start and End Dates.

The Objects will look like this:

```
public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Employee
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public IList<EmploymentTerm> EmploymentTerms { get; set; }
}

public class EmploymentTerm
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Store Store { get; set; }
    public Employee Employee { get; set; }
    public DateTime? StartDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

Did this freehand so there could be a couple errors.